# How to change data from null to 0?

Tags: javascript, nan

My data from db is null. I have divided this data with 1 other data with a value of 0 and the result into NaN.

```
 $(".js-view-project-year").text(mathRound(response.data.importPhase.allError.allError / response.data.importPhase.countError.countError));
```

I want change data from 0 to NaN

Comment: `((response.data.importPhase.allError.allError || 0)/(response.data.importPhase.countError.countError || 1))` try this

Comment: The subject is 'data from null to 0', but the conclusion is 'data from 0 to NaN'. What do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if your result is `NaN`

```
result = mathRound(allError / countError)

isNaN(result) ? '0' : result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `result = 0` this is when you want DB returns `null` value.

Then check value returned by DB is not `false, null, Nan`. If yes then and then use in division.

In JavaScript when you use `if` and the expression is one of the following `false, null, Nan, undefined` then it results into `false`.

```
let result = 0;
if(response.data.importPhase.countError.countError){
   result = mathRound(response.data.importPhase.allError.allError / response.data.importPhase.countError.countError) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use short circuiting OR!

This will return the first value if it truthy, else (in case of `0` or `NaN`) the second (which is `0`).

```
mathRound(response.data.importPhase.allError.allError / response.data.importPhase.countError.countError) || 0
```